# Scrapy - response body contains javascript and unable to xpath select

Tags: python, scrapy, screen-scraping

So I'm having an issue with scraping this page

https://www.tribeofdumo.com/nefertiti-infinity-dress.

There is some javascript in the response body and I am unable to `xpath` select the individual products listed on that page. I'm basically trying to select the `li.gallery-item` which I can only see when doing an inspect element and not view source.

If you do a view source on that page that is pretty much what the response.body is. Also, I guessed maybe scrapy isn't able to render the javascript, so I installed Splash and tried to render the page but even with splash I get the same output and the screenshot does not even show the products.

Comment: So i figured out the answer to this. I basically used selenium instead and used the driver.switch_to.frame method to switch to the iframe that contained the products and then extracted the html content. using the driver.execute_script method.

Comment: I'd like to add that Selenium and Splash should both work fine. There is a FAQ section on Splash documentation that should help you in case page is not being rendered as expected. And also, as you already know by now, _scrapy isn't able to render the javascript_ is a true statement.